# Which property is it that makes the background white?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

As you can see here, the corner is white, I want it to be transparent, and I know things can go wrong with WPF where transparent becomes white but then I could just change the color to the background color.

[image]

So my question is, which property is it that I need to change to make sure that the corner right there isn't white?

```
<Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="menuParentStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryLighter}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>


        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Foreground" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid Margin="-1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                        <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryLighter}"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Yellow"/>-->
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate2" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="Orange" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    CornerRadius="5">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFD7D7D7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryLighter}"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>-->
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>


    </Window.Resources>
```

**Implementation**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="_File" Style="{StaticResource menuParentStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" >
            <MenuItem Header="_New"  />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Quit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Style="{StaticResource menuParentStyle}"  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}"  Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}">
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Cut" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Paste" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: *"As you can see here, the corner is white"* - I don't see white corners. Could you clarify the problem? Since you are saying *corner* my nuts tells `CornerRadius`, but I am not sure.

Comment: I added a picture that shows the white corner.

Comment: I see a white corner.. but i also know I had issues with some things and trying to find the area that covered it, for example I made a load of graphs.. but some had borders I couldnt get rid of for the same reason, it was like according to everything they didnt exist.

Comment: I updated the image, it has those corners all around

Comment: @BugFinder, `SnapToDevicePixels` issues? I recall it's not enough, there are more properties exists.

Comment: You forgot to incude the markup that shows how your styles are applied in your question.

Comment: @VargaDev have you set your grid background to say "black" or "transparent" it doesnt seem obvious but like so much with these things its easy to find yourself missing it

Comment: I've now added it @mm8

Comment: @VargaDev: Did you try to set the background of the Menu? It's still unclear where the black and white come from given your sample markup.

Comment: The blacka nd white is from when you click the actual menu and it shows the Menuitems, the MenuItems backgrounds are black with a white foreground as shown here https://i.imgur.com/o2Q4jS8.png

Comment: Omg, I was setting the background of the MenuItem and not the menu.. I really need to stop coding as soon as I wake up..

Comment: @mm8 Feel free to post a answer with what you commented regarding the `Menu` background color, and I'll grab a coffee meanwhile, and i'll accept it when I get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `Background` property of the parent `Menu` element:

```
<Menu Background="Transparent" ...>
```